# Get 500 server error with OfficeOpenXml on local host?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I dont know why i get this error im running on local host. I get the error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). It goes to Changefile first then it goes to ToDatatable().

```
  public async Task<string> ChangeFileAsync(IList<IFormFile> files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName));
        if (Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName)==".xlsx")
        {
            ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage((Stream)files[0]);
            DataTable Dt = ExcelPackageExtensions.ToDataTable(package);
        }
        return "Function worked";
    }






 internal static DataTable ToDataTable(ExcelPackage package)
    {
        ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First(); //This line gives the error
        DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
        foreach(var firstRowCell in workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column])
        {
            Dt.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text);
        }
        for(var rowNumber = 2; rowNumber <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;rowNumber++)
        {
            var row = workSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1,rowNumber, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column];
            var newRow = Dt.NewRow();
            foreach(var cell in row)
            {
                newRow[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
            }
            Dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }

        return Dt;
    }
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)